# Is my internet faster using a VPN?

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn, internet-speed

I'm at an airport now, and I'm on my college's computer they provide us that includes the Adobe suite.  If we want to use any of the programs, we have to connect to the university's network using a VPN.  When I ran a speed test before the VPN, I was getting around 3 mbps, and once I connected to the VPN, I got around 42 mbps.  Is this testing the internet connection to my university?

Answer (score 3):

Normally the answer would be no.

VPN goes over internet, so VPN can only ever be as fast as the internet connection it is going through. In fact, it passes over 2 internet connections. One at the university and one at the airport. The slowest internet connection of the two is the maximum speed the VPN can get.

However, with lots of people on the internet at an airport, you will never get the full speed it offers. Visitors are always given only a fraction of the speed so everyone can use internet at the same time. It does this by analysing the packets that are sent over.

By using a VPN connection, the airport can't correctly classify the connection, and given that business people often require a VPN connection to connect to their office, they have set QualityOfService to prioritize the VPN connection over standard traffic.

So the TL;DR answer would be: No, but with VPN your internet is less slowed down.

Answer (score 0):

They might be throttling that specific website. I know that most airports throttle sites such as  Youtube and Netflix.

In general, unless you have a super-high quality VPN which can low the amount of hops it takes to get to your destination, VPNs will slow your speeds.

Comment: How can a VPN decrease the amount of hops?